# post request without a form or a button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post

So I have to make a post request without a `form` or a `button`. I have the `patientInfo` array that is rendered on a table. When the user chooses a location for a patient, then that patient will have a `timestamp` value. When the patient in the array has a timestamp that's when I am supposed to auto `post` the patient with the timestamp.

My `handleAutoObsSubmit()` is kinda working but the problem is, it maps over the `patienArray` and sends the patient multiple time so if the user chooses the third patient's location, there will be three object of the same patient that is sent.

Another issue I am having with is `componentDidUpdate`, it sends the post request every second. I suspect that is because the patient count is being count down every sec. Not 100% sure though. Is it even a good idea to send post request in `componentDidUpdate`?

```
patientInfo = [
            { count: 100, room: "1", name: 'John Nero', timeStamp: '', location: ''},
            { count: 100, room: "2", name: 'Shawn Michael', timeStamp: '', location: ''},
            { count: 100, room: "3", name: 'Gereth Macneil', timeStamp: '', location: ''}
 ]
```

```
handleAutoObsSubmit = () => {

        const postUrl = '/send_patient_that_has_timeStamp';
        const timeStampedPatients = this.state.patientInfo.filter(patient => patient.timeStamp !== '');
        let data = {};

        timeStampedPatients.map((patient) => {

            data = {
                room: patient.room,
                patient: patient.name,
                timestamp: patient.timeStamp,
                location: patient.locationInfo,
            };

        });


        fetch(postUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then((res) => {

                if (!res.ok) {
                    console.log('request failed');
                } else {
                    console.log('request sent');
                }
            });
    }
```

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
        this.state.patientInfo.map(patient => {
            if (patient.timeStamp !== '') {
                this.handleAutoObsSubmit();
            }
        });
    }
```

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {

            this.setState(prevState => ({

                patientInfo: prevState.patientInfo.map((patient) => {
                    if (patient.locationInfo!== '') {

                        if (patient.count <= 0) {
                            clearInterval(this.countDownInterval);
                        }
                        return { ...patient, count: patient.count - 1 };
                    }
                    return patient;
                })
            }));
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: How does the patient get a timestamp? Does someone manually put a timestamp on the patient by editing the table?

Comment: @MattOestreich No, when the user clicks patient location button the onClick() updates the state of the patient with the location and the timestamp. Its not on UI, timeStamp is set onClick()

Comment: Are you sure that the handleAutoObsSubmit isn't being called 3 times instead of sending the patient Obj 3 times?

Comment: @Jereme does my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle it in a similar fashion to this:

```js
function Table() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([
    {
      name: "John Doe",
      timestamp: ""
    },
    {
      name: "Jane Doe",
      timestamp: ""
    },
    {
      name: "Nancy Doe",
      timestamp: ""
    }
  ]);

  const updateItem = (event, index) => {
    let newstate = [...tableData];
    newstate[index].timestamp = (new Date(Date.now())).toString();
    alert(`Do POST here: ${JSON.stringify(newstate[index],null,2)}`);
    setTableData(newstate);
  };
  
  return (
    <table border="5">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div>Patient</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div>Timestamp</div>
        </th>
        <th>Update</th>
      </tr>
      {tableData.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td style={{width:'410px'}}>{item.timestamp}</td>
            <td>
              <button 
                style={{backgroundColor:'green', color:'white'}} 
                onClick={event => updateItem(event, index)}>
                UPDATE
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```